# NodeJs respond with JSON to python after getting POST request

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json, express

Cant figure out how to respond with JSON data from Node server to python after receiving post request from python.

Node js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require('request');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.post("/postdata",(req,res)=>{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var a = req.body.name;
    var b = req.body.job;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);

    var json={
        "name":"Bobby",
        "job":"Cook"
    } 

    res.json(JSON.stringify(json));

})
app.listen(3000);
```

Python

```py
import requests
import json

url='http://localhost:3000/postdata'
headers = {"content-type":"application/json"}

requests.post(url,
    json={
        "name":"Edward",
        "job":"Teacher"
    })

data = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

print(data)
```

I do get the result Edward, teacher in the node server console after running the python script.
But from the the python i got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pClient.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Could you please share what the content of the response on python's end? Just print the contents of response.text

Comment: Your Python code makes two requests, but your JavaScript code only handles one of them.

Comment: This is the result after running data.text without .json() '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /postdata</pre>
</body>
</html>'''

Comment: @jonrsharpe , So does it mean i need to create another url for Nodejs to send json to python? I thought after the node received a post request, it will be able to send a response back to the client, am i wrong ?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the response to a POST request, which you *have* implemented in Express, with making a second request, a GET, which you haven't.

Comment: @jonrshape Ok I understood now, I just removed the get request and print the result of the POST request from python, and it got the the result: Bobby, cook from the node server .Thank you.